# How to work with an Opportunistic Subscription in Android?

Tags: android, telephony, android-subscriptionmanager

I want to make use of the Opportunistic Subscription as part of the SubscriptionManager in Android.

Two questions:

1. Where can I find more documentation for the Opportunistic Subscription? I only see some info here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager
2. It seems I need permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

But this requires the application to be a System App. Is this then at all feasible?

Kind regards
Jens Buysse

Answer (score 0):

@Jens Buysse

To answer your questions

1. Android developer subscription manager documentation have very good information regarding the Opportunistic Subscription, You can know more about the Opportunistic subscription APIs by checking Telephony manager as well https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager
2. Yes, your app needs to be an system app with all the privileged permissions and system permissions to leverage the Opportunistic subscription API's. on top of that you need carrier privileges' as well for your application to work.